# How do I make an button look "visually held down" when it is clicked/pressed

Tags: android, android-layout

Right now I have a functioning button in my dialog where:

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(...) {
    ...
    final Button storeButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_store);
    storeButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MyClass.this, StoreListViewActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
    });
}
```

How would I get the button to look pressed (i.e. visually held down) when it is clicked/on a long press? I don't have a XML file for this class because I'm trying to avoid modifying it. I tried to look through the methods for the view but I can't find any. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to simply change the tint of the button to show it is pressed (this also works for long presses):

Implement OnTouchListener and override this method:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.btn_play:
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            btnPlay.setColorFilter(Color.argb(100, 37, 169, 208));
        else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
            btnPlay.setColorFilter(Color.argb(0, 0, 228, 253));
        break;
    case R.id.btnBuy:
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            btnBuy.setColorFilter(Color.argb(255, 37, 169, 208));
        else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
            btnBuy.setColorFilter(Color.argb(0, 0, 228, 253));
        break;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Adjust the number values to your desired color.

Answer (score 1):

Simply replace its background to a new `Drawable` in the `onClick` method, or layout file where you would create that "held down" effect. For instance:

```
your_button.setDrawableByLayerId(R.id.imagen_fondo, getResources().getDrawable(new_drawable));
```